# How do I print a grid from a list of lists with numbered rows and columns

Tags: python, list, printing, python-3.3, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a grid that's `n_rows` by `n_columns`, which will be changeable. This is my code; it takes a list of lists and the two dimension integers:

```
def _print_board(game_state: list, n_rows: int, n_columns: int)-> None:
    for i in range(n_rows):
        if i+1 < 10:
            print(i+1, '', end=' ')
        else:
            print(i+1, end=' ')
        for j in range(n_columns):
            if game_state[j][i] == NONE:
                print('.', end=' ')
            elif game_state[j][i] == WHITE:
                print(WHITE, end=' ')
            elif game_state[j][i] == BLACK:
                print(BLACK, end=' ')
        else:
            print('\n',end='')
```

The output I get is:

```
1  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
2  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
3  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
4  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
5  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
6  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
7  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
8  . . . . . . . B W . . . . . . . 
9  . . . . . . . W B . . . . . . . 
10 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
11 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
12 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
13 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
14 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
15 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
16 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

So I get numbered rows but I can't figure out how to format numbered columns properly, meaning that each dot aligns up with the row and column number. I would like to get something like this, but with each dot also aligned with the column number:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
2  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
3  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
4  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
5  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
6  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
7  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
8  . . . . . . . B W . . . . . . . 
9  . . . . . . . W B . . . . . . . 
10 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
11 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
12 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
13 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
14 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
15 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
16 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

The column numbers can be on top or bottom, but I prefer them on top. How do I make it so that the dots align with the column numbers and there won't be those two numbers hanging off the edge? 16 is the max dimension for the grid, so this is the largest grid I would print.

Comment: You will notice that they go out of sync when the numbers reach two digits - do you want the same spacing all across?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah I noticed that for the rows I was able to just add a space after rows 1-9, but doing that for the columns will make the grid look weird so yes I would like the same spacing all across so that everything is symmetric.

Comment: Oh good, that's the easiest to deal with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to format all numbers to two characters:

```
def _print_board(game_state):
    print(" ".join("{0:2d}".format(i) if i else "  " # or 0:02d to pad with zero
                   for i in range(len(game_state[0]) + 1)))
    for i, row in enumerate(game_state, 1):
        print("{0:2d}".format(i), end=" ")
        print("".join(" {0} ".format(col if col != NONE else ".") for col in row))
```

Note that you don't need to pass the sizes if you can get them from `game_state`. For a 12x4 grid, this gives me:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 2  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 3  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

---

Expanding the above function a bit:

```
def _print_board(game_state):
    # headers
    for i in range(len(game_state[0]) + 1):
        if i == 0:
            # column for row numbers
            print("   ", end="")
        else:
            # column headers
            print("{0:2d} ".format(i), end="")
    print()
    for i, row in enumerate(game_state, 1):
        # row number
        print("{0:2d} ".format(i), end="")
        for col in row:
            # row data
            if col == NONE:
                print(" {0} ".format("."), end="")
            else:
                print(" {0} ".format(col), end="")
        print()
```

Comment: Your code worked, but I'm having trouble understanding what you did exactly would you mind writing it in a less compact form. Also, thank you I forgot the game_state already knew the sizes.

Comment: Edited with an expanded version, but it is worth going through and understanding the compact version too

Comment: Yes I've been looking at the compact version, but thank you for the expanded version it's really easy to understand with the comments.